Running flink on Zeppelin reports the error "Fail to open FlinkInterpreter"
I bound flink to Zeppelin and tried running the Batch WordCount example but I kept getting errors.
%flink

val data = benv.fromElements("hello world", "hello flink", "hello hadoop")
data.flatMap(line => line.split("\\s"))
             .map(w => (w, 1))
             .groupBy(0)
             .sum(1)
             .print()

ERROR
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open FlinkInterpreter
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at 
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the DispatcherResourceManagerComponent.

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Could not start rest endpoint on any port in port range 8089

Extract from the background log，I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong
org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkStreamSqlInterpreter1182951841 with maxConcurrency: 10
2024-05-16 19:18:40,675 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.SchedulerFactory               [] - Create FIFOScheduler: interpreter_275379926
2024-05-16 19:18:40,684 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.SchedulerFactory               [] - Create FIFOScheduler: interpreter_2130891230
2024-05-16 19:18:40,711 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler              [] - Job paragraph_1580998080340_1531975932 started by scheduler interpreter_1133597353
2024-05-16 19:18:40,739 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkInterpreter                   [] - Using Scala: version 2.12.7
2024-05-16 19:18:40,896 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkScala212Interpreter           [] - Using flink: 1.13.1          [] - UserJars: 
2024-05-16 19:18:42,356 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkScala212Interpreter           [] - Config: Config(None,None,Some([Ljava.lang.String;@2b6f56a4),LOCAL,Some(YarnConfig(Some(1024m),Some(Zeppelin Flink Session),Some(default),Some(1),Some(1024m))),None)
2024-05-16 19:18:42,376 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkScala212Interpreter           [] - Default Parallelism: 1
2024-05-16 19:18:42,376 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkScala212Interpreter           [] - Default SQL Parallelism: -1
2024-05-16 19:18:42,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration                 [] - Config uses fallback configuration key 'jobmanager.rpc.address' instead of key 'rest.address'
2024-05-16 19:18:42,396 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils [] - The resource configuration option Key: 'taskmanager.memory.process.size' , default: null (fallback keys: []) is set but it will have no effect for local execution, only the following options matter for the resource configuration: [Key: 'taskmanager.memory.process.size' , default: null (fallback keys: []), Key: 'taskmanager.memory.flink.size' , default: null (fallback keys: []), Key: 'taskmanager.memory.framework.heap.size' , default: 128 mb (fallback keys: []), Key: 'taskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.size' , default: 128 mb (fallback keys: []), Key: 'taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size' , default: 256 mb (fallback keys: []), Key: 'taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.min' , default: 192 mb (fallback keys: []), Key: 'taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max' , default: 1 gb (fallback keys: []), Key: 'taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.fraction' , default: 0.1 (fallback keys: [])]
2024-05-16 19:18:42,398 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils [] - The configuration option taskmanager.cpu.cores required for local execution is not set, setting it to the maximal possible value.
2024-05-16 19:18:42,398 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorResourceUtils [] - The cStarting Metrics Registry
2024-05-16 19:18:42,447 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl          [] - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
2024-05-16 19:18:42,447 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster             [] - Starting RPC Service(s)
2024-05-16 19:18:42,458 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils        [] - Trying to start local actor system
2024-05-16 19:18:43,522 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                 [] - Slf4jLogger started
2024-05-16 19:18:44,145 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils        [] - Actor system started at akka://flink
2024-05-16 19:18:44,243 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils        [] - Trying to start local actor system
2024-05-16 19:18:44,284 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                 [] - Slf4jLogger started
2024-05-16 19:18:44,307 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils        [] - Actor system started at akka://flink-metrics
2024-05-16 19:18:44,325 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.dump.MetricQueryService at akka://flink-metrics/user/rpc/MetricQueryService .
2024-05-16 19:18:44,537 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster             [] - Starting high-availability services
2024-05-16 19:18:44,547 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                     [] - Created BLOB server storage directory /tmp/blobStore-de8b3b47-41b9-4026-bcad-594d882c7394
2024-05-16 19:18:44,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                     [] - Started BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:35315 - max concurrent requests: 50 - max backlog: 1000
2024-05-16 19:18:44,553 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.PermanentBlobCache             [] - Created BLOB cache storage directory /tmp/blobStore-e14dd654-cd72-459f-8e39-ebecb23b5de8
2024-05-16 19:18:44,556 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache             [] - Created BLOB cache storage directory /tmp/blobStore-ef08a1bf-16d3-4341-8130-19b7086399c9
2024-05-16 19:18:44,557 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster             [] - Starting 4 TaskManger(s)
2024-05-16 19:18:44,559 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner      [] - Starting TaskManager with ResourceID: cb840e4d-a723-4425-b06b-1d3a2c7109ec
2024-05-16 19:18:44,578 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerServices    [] - Temporary file directory '/tmp': total 17 GB, usable 4 GB (23.53% usable)
2024-05-16 19:18:44,580 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.FileChannelManagerImpl      [] - FileChannelManager uses directory /tmp/flink-io-d857752d-3823-4725-8aa0-83497a3b7f14 for spill files.
2024-05-16 19:18:44,779 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyConfig        [] - NettyConfig [server address: /0.0.0.0, server port: 0, ssl enabled: false, memory segment size (bytes): 32768, transport type: AUTO, number of server threads: 1 (manual), number of client threads: 1 (manual), server connect backlog: 0 (use Netty's default), client connect timeout (sec): 120, send/receive buffer size (bytes): 0 (use Netty's default)]
2024-05-16 19:18:44,781 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.FileChannelManagerImpl      [] - FileChannelManager uses directory /tmp/flink-netty-shuffle-8286752b-510f-49cf-8616-1313d23a0c37 for spill files.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,017 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool [] - Allocated 64 MB for network buffer pool (number of memory segments: 2048, bytes per segment: 32768).
2024-05-16 19:18:46,035 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NettyShuffleEnvironment  [] - Starting the network environment and its components.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,130 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient        [] - Transport type 'auto': using EPOLL.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,135 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient        [] - Successful initialization (took 99 ms).
2024-05-16 19:18:46,162 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer        [] - Transport type 'auto': using EPOLL.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,277 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer        [] -
2024-05-16 19:18:46,410 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner      [] - Starting TaskManager with ResourceID: 02239aa3-a3a0-41cb-89d0-18eab6e966a6
2024-05-16 19:18:46,411 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerServices    [] - Temporary file directory '/tmp': total 17 GB, usable 4 GB (23.53% usable)
2024-05-16 19:18:46,411 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.FileChannelManagerImpl      [] - FileChannelManager uses directory /tmp/flink-io-4c98fa0c-fd0a-4479-af04-c23e81794ffe for spill files.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,411 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.DefaultJobLeaderService [] - Start job leader service.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,851 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool [] - Allocated 64 MB for network buffer pool (number of memory segments: 2048, bytes per segment: 32768).
2024-05-16 19:18:46,851 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NettyShuffleEnvironment  [] - Starting the network environment and its components.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,852 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient        [] - Transport type 'auto': using EPOLL.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,859 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner      [] - Starting TaskManager with ResourceID: 6150b4e8-26e5-440f-8f29-60a4a72f1623
2024-05-16 19:18:46,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerServices    [] - Temporary file directory '/tmp': total 17 GB, usable 4 GB (23.53% usable)
2024-05-16 19:18:46,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.FileChannelManagerImpl      [] - FileChannelManager uses directory /tmp/flink-io-7783301e-31e2-457c-bc4c-adc41d123eb7 for spill files.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.DefaultJobLeaderService [] - Start job leader service.
2024-05-16 19:18:46,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                 [] - User file cache uses directory /tmp/flink-dist-cache-804c64cd-c835-4a90-8d0e-12bfc05ed1e8
2024-05-16 19:18:46,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyConfig        [] - NettyConfig [server address: /0.0.0.0, server port: 0, ssl enabled: false, memory segment size (bytes): 32768, transport type: AUTO, number of server threads: 1 (manual), number of client threads: 1 (manual), server connect backlog: 0 (use Netty's default), client connect timeout (sec): 120, send/receive buffer size (bytes): 0 (use Netty's default)]
2024-05-16 19:18:46,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.FileChannelManagerImpl      [] - FileChannelManager uses directory /tmp/flink-netty-shuffle-c33c1493-5e9b-4e3f-a938-d8d24676758e for spill files.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,695 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool [] - Allocated 64 MB for network buffer pool (number of memory segments: 2048, bytes per segment: 32768).
2024-05-16 19:18:47,696 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NettyShuffleEnvironment  [] - Starting the network environment and its components.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,697 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient        [] - Transport type 'auto': using EPOLL.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,697 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient        [] - Successful initialization (took 1 ms).
2024-05-16 19:18:47,698 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer        [] - Transport type 'auto': using EPOLL.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,701 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer        [] - Successful initialization (took 4 ms). Listening on SocketAddress /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:44986.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,701 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.KvStateService         [] - Starting the kvState service and its components.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,715 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor at akka://flink/user/rpc/taskmanager_2 .
2024-05-16 19:18:47,715 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner      [] - Starting TaskManager with ResourceID: f37294e6-dfc5-432c-9a5a-9d04800c28e7
2024-05-16 19:18:47,715 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.DefaultJobLeaderService [] - Start job leader service.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,716 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                 [] - User file cache uses directory /tmp/flink-dist-cache-63183c38-e7b0-46db-87e6-d2097b3f1a5a
2024-05-16 19:18:47,716 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerServices    [] - Temporary file directory '/tmp': total 17 GB, usable 4 GB (23.53% usable)
2024-05-16 19:18:47,716 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.FileChannelManagerImpl      [] - FileChannelManager uses directory /tmp/flink-io-45de5114-524b-4b43-9228-08f2bca8f5d5 for spill files.
2024-05-16 19:18:47,718 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyConfig        [] - NettyConfig [server address: /0.0.0.0, server port: 0, ssl enabled: false, memory segment size (bytes): 32768, transport type: AUTO, number of server threads: 1 (manual), number of client threads: 1 (manual), server connect backlog: 0 (use Netty's default), client connect timeout (sec): 120, send/receive buffer size (bytes): 0 (use Netty's default)]
2024-05-16 19:18:47,718 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.FileChannelManagerImpl      [] - FileChannelManager uses directory /tmp/flink-netty-shuffle-83242c8b-396f-488e-a69b-14ab1cf72c6e for spill files.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,324 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool [] - Allocated 64 MB for network buffer pool (number of memory segments: 2048, bytes per segment: 32768).
2024-05-16 19:18:48,325 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NettyShuffleEnvironment  [] - Starting the network environment and its components.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,325 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient        [] - Transport type 'auto': using EPOLL.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,325 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient        [] - Successful initialization (took 0 ms).
2024-05-16 19:18:48,326 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer        [] - Transport type 'auto': using EPOLL.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,327 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer        [] - Successful initialization (took 1 ms). Listening on SocketAddress /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:46336.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,327 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.KvStateService         [] - Starting the kvState service and its components.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,330 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor at akka://flink/user/rpc/taskmanager_3 .
2024-05-16 19:18:48,330 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.DefaultJobLeaderService [] - Start job leader service.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,330 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                 [] - User file cache uses directory /tmp/flink-dist-cache-59a203bc-6341-4dac-ad99-89e1fa8e620c
2024-05-16 19:18:48,351 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration                 [] - Config uses fallback configuration key 'rest.port' instead of key 'rest.bind-port'
2024-05-16 19:18:48,365 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint   [] - Starting rest endpoint.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,884 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils          [] - Log file environment variable 'log.file' is not set.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,884 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils          [] - JobManager log files are unavailable in the web dashboard. Log file location not found in environment variable 'log.file' or configuration key 'web.log.path'.
2024-05-16 19:18:48,974 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint   [] - Shutting down rest endpoint.
2024-05-16 19:18:49,001 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkScala212Interpreter           [] - Closing FlinkScalaInterpreter
2024-05-16 19:18:49,033 INFO  org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler              [] - Job paragraph_1580998080340_1531975932 finished by scheduler interpreter_1133597353 with status ERROR

This is flink-conf.yaml ，I adjusted taskmanager.memory.process.size
################################################################################
#  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
#  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
#  distributed with this work for additional information
#  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
#  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
#  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
#  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
################################################################################


#==============================================================================
# Common
#==============================================================================

# The external address of the host on which the JobManager runs and can be
# reached by the TaskManagers and any clients which want to connect. This setting
# is only used in Standalone mode and may be overwritten on the JobManager side
# by specifying the --host <hostname> parameter of the bin/jobmanager.sh executable.
# In high availability mode, if you use the bin/start-cluster.sh script and setup
# the conf/masters file, this will be taken care of automatically. Yarn/Mesos
# automatically configure the host name based on the hostname of the node where the
# JobManager runs.

jobmanager.rpc.address: master

# The RPC port where the JobManager is reachable.

jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123

env.java.home: /home/hadoop/jdk1.8.0_271
# The total process memory size for the JobManager.
#
# Note this accounts for all memory usage within the JobManager process, including JVM metaspace and other overhead.

jobmanager.memory.process.size: 1600m


# The total process memory size for the TaskManager.
#
# Note this accounts for all memory usage within the TaskManager process, including JVM metaspace and other overhead.

taskmanager.memory.process.size: 2048m

# To exclude JVM metaspace and overhead, please, use total Flink memory size instead of 'taskmanager.memory.process.size'.
# It is not recommended to set both 'taskmanager.memory.process.size' and Flink memory.
#
# taskmanager.memory.flink.size: 1280m

# The number of task slots that each TaskManager offers. Each slot runs one parallel pipeline.

taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 30

# The parallelism used for programs that did not specify and other parallelism.

parallelism.default: 1

# The default file system scheme and authority.
# 
# By default file paths without scheme are interpreted relative to the local
# root file system 'file:///'. Use this to override the default and interpret
# relative paths relative to a different file system,
# for example 'hdfs://mynamenode:12345'
#
# fs.default-scheme

#==============================================================================
# High Availability
#==============================================================================

# The high-availability mode. Possible options are 'NONE' or 'zookeeper'.
#
# high-availability: zookeeper

# The path where metadata for master recovery is persisted. While ZooKeeper stores
# the small ground truth for checkpoint and leader election, this location stores
# the larger objects, like persisted dataflow graphs.
# 
# Must be a durable file system that is accessible from all nodes
# (like HDFS, S3, Ceph, nfs, ...) 
#
# high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///flink/ha/

# The list of ZooKeeper quorum peers that coordinate the high-availability
# setup. This must be a list of the form:
# "host1:clientPort,host2:clientPort,..." (default clientPort: 2181)
#
# high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: localhost:2181


# ACL options are based on https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_BuiltinACLSchemes
# It can be either "creator" (ZOO_CREATE_ALL_ACL) or "open" (ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE)
# The default value is "open" and it can be changed to "creator" if ZK security is enabled
#
# high-availability.zookeeper.client.acl: open

#==============================================================================
# Fault tolerance and checkpointing
#==============================================================================

# The backend that will be used to store operator state checkpoints if
# checkpointing is enabled.
#
# Supported backends are 'jobmanager', 'filesystem', 'rocksdb', or the
# <class-name-of-factory>.
#
# state.backend: filesystem

# Directory for checkpoints filesystem, when using any of the default bundled
# state backends.
#
# state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs://namenode-host:port/flink-checkpoints

# Default target directory for savepoints, optional.
#
# state.savepoints.dir: hdfs://namenode-host:port/flink-savepoints

# Flag to enable/disable incremental checkpoints for backends that
# support incremental checkpoints (like the RocksDB state backend). 
#
# state.backend.incremental: false

# The failover strategy, i.e., how the job computation recovers from task failures.
# Only restart tasks that may have been affected by the task failure, which typically includes
# downstream tasks and potentially upstream tasks if their produced data is no longer available for consumption.

jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy: region

#==============================================================================
# Rest & web frontend
#==============================================================================

# The port to which the REST client connects to. If rest.bind-port has
# not been specified, then the server will bind to this port as well.
#
rest.port: 8089

# The address to which the REST client will connect to
#
#rest.address: 0.0.0.0

# Port range for the REST and web server to bind to.
#
#rest.bind-port: 8080-8090

# The address that the REST & web server binds to
#
#rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0

# Flag to specify whether job submission is enabled from the web-based
# runtime monitor. Uncomment to disable.

#web.submit.enable: false

#==============================================================================
# Advanced
#==============================================================================

# Override the directories for temporary files. If not specified, the
# system-specific Java temporary directory (java.io.tmpdir property) is taken.
#
# For framework setups on Yarn or Mesos, Flink will automatically pick up the
# containers' temp directories without any need for configuration.
#
# Add a delimited list for multiple directories, using the system directory
# delimiter (colon ':' on unix) or a comma, e.g.:
#     /data1/tmp:/data2/tmp:/data3/tmp
#
# Note: Each directory entry is read from and written to by a different I/O
# thread. You can include the same directory multiple times in order to create
# multiple I/O threads against that directory. This is for example relevant for
# high-throughput RAIDs.
#
# io.tmp.dirs: /tmp

# The classloading resolve order. Possible values are 'child-first' (Flink's default)
# and 'parent-first' (Java's default).
#
# Child first classloading allows users to use different dependency/library
# versions in their application than those in the classpath. Switching back
# to 'parent-first' may help with debugging dependency issues.
#
classloader.resolve-order: parent-first

# The amount of memory going to the network stack. These numbers usually need 
# no tuning. Adjusting them may be necessary in case of an "Insufficient number
# of network buffers" error. The default min is 64MB, the default max is 1GB.
# 
# taskmanager.memory.network.fraction: 0.1
#taskmanager.memory.network.min: 64mb
#taskmanager.memory.network.max: 1gb

#==============================================================================
# Flink Cluster Security Configuration
#==============================================================================

# Kerberos authentication for various components - Hadoop, ZooKeeper, and connectors -
# may be enabled in four steps:
# 1. configure the local krb5.conf file
# 2. provide Kerberos credentials (either a keytab or a ticket cache w/ kinit)
# 3. make the credentials available to various JAAS login contexts
# 4. configure the connector to use JAAS/SASL

# The below configure how Kerberos credentials are provided. A keytab will be used instead of
# a ticket cache if the keytab path and principal are set.

# security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache: true
# security.kerberos.login.keytab: /path/to/kerberos/keytab
# security.kerberos.login.principal: flink-user

# The configuration below defines which JAAS login contexts

# security.kerberos.login.contexts: Client,KafkaClient

#==============================================================================
# ZK Security Configuration
#==============================================================================

# Below configurations are applicable if ZK ensemble is configured for security

# Override below configuration to provide custom ZK service name if configured
# zookeeper.sasl.service-name: zookeeper

# The configuration below must match one of the values set in "security.kerberos.login.contexts"
# zookeeper.sasl.login-context-name: Client

#==============================================================================
# HistoryServer
#==============================================================================

# The HistoryServer is started and stopped via bin/historyserver.sh (start|stop)

# Directory to upload completed jobs to. Add this directory to the list of
# monitored directories of the HistoryServer as well (see below).
#jobmanager.archive.fs.dir: hdfs:///completed-jobs/

# The address under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
#historyserver.web.address: 0.0.0.0

# The port under which the web-based HistoryServer listens.
#historyserver.web.port: 8082

# Comma separated list of directories to monitor for completed jobs.
#historyserver.archive.fs.dir: hdfs:///completed-jobs/

# Interval in milliseconds for refreshing the monitored directories.
#historyserver.archive.fs.refresh-interval: 10000

